# How to go full screen on IDLE on a mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I wanted to know whether I could use fullscreen on IDLE on a mac, so that I can code without any interruptions.

I have already tried the maximize button but it’s of no use for going full screen.

Comment: The maximize button works for me, unless we have different understandings of what full-screen means.

Comment: I have had the same result:  1) open a terminal, 2) issue /usr/bin/idle, 3)windows is created, 3) press the green full-screen button.  Are you following a different procedure?

Comment: I pressed the green button, but it only enlarges of the screen. It doesn’t expand it fully in the screen.The dock and menubar are still visible.

Comment: @Gardener  I opened IDLE and pressed the green button.

Comment: Does the green button have an `x` or a `+` symbol or two diagnollay opposed triangles, just before you press it?

Comment: @Gardener it had sort of an x symbol you would normally have with other full screen apps

Comment: Mine has two diagonally opposed triangles.  I only have an 'x' over the red button.  I have a '+' over the green button when I bring up the options screen.  I think you have a mac osx issue rather than a python or idle issue.  Good luck.

Comment: @Gardener bro i meant that itself, i meant the normal fullscreen button